# Internationalization of ASP.NET apps

Tags: asp.net, internationalization

How do you guys handle translation/internationalization of your ASP.NET applications? How do you work with your translators?

We have ASP.NET apps that need to be available in German, French, Italian, English. We use string resources everywhere. However, more than once, our translators have told us just getting a bunch of "txtMyTextbox.Text" and then a German text to be translated is next to impossible to deal with - the context is missing.

So are there any other solutions available? Due to the fact these translators are dispersed all over Europe, we cannot get them to fly in and do their work "on location" - there has to be a way to send them the text fragments to be translated, along with some context, and let them do their work.

Is there any tool out there that would allow me to package up my ASPX pages and ASCX controls along with the text resources, and that would actually visualize them to the translator (without him having to install and host IIS and all) ? I vaguely remember there was a lot one tool in my olden Delphi days that did that - visualize the form (without the real app running), and allowing someone to pick the labels and translate them.

Or would there be a tool that would allow me to make screenshots of my ASPX pages and highlight all label and display their control name ("txtMytextbox") in red, so that the screenshot could serve as an orientation help for someone working on translating a list of labels?

Any hints are most welcome and highly appreciated!

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the Lingobit http://www.lingobit.com/

Comment: Looks interesting, but the ASP.NET internationalization seems to be limited to just presenting a list of local and global resource strings - I already have that, what I need is a visualization of the ASP.NET based context (the webform and user controls).

Answer (score 2):

How about going around ASP.NET's insternationalization scheme and using a diferent approach, using .po files like the "rest of the world" . The actual text is the key, and translators see that text qhen they are translating. Works pretty well.

http://www.expatsoftware.com/articles/2010/03/fixing-internationalization-in-aspnet.html

describes this.

Answer (score 0):

- Make your resource keys more meaningful. This will give them *some* context
- Can the translators get access to a running app? If so, you could set the tooltips of all your labels to be the resource key. That would allow them to mouse over a label to see where its string is coming from.
- As your translators become more familiar with the product, they'll be able to better cope with the lack of context. The first time around is a little rough, and you'll need to go through a few rounds of testing and translation revisions. There's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Well, we try to make the resource keys as meaningful as we can - but that's not good enough :-( And no, unfortunately, there's currently no way the translators would have access to the running app :-( And since those translators are picked each time something needs to be done, there's hardly any "learning" effect - whoever is available right now gets the contract .....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article written by Scott Hanselman. Hope it helps
  [Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)

Comment: Provide atleast a small extract. Link only answers are not preferred on SO.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. i will correct it from now on.