# Providing multi language support in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, localization

I am developing a new web application from scratch. I need to provide multi-language support in my website. Which enable users from different regions of the world to see each web page in their own language.

Since, i am new to this field so i don't know how to achieve this. One possible way is to make each single page multiple times for each different language :(

But i am not will to do so, because it increases the development and maintenance time.

Secondly, what to do with the database, do i need to make some considerations while designing database?

I will develop this site using ASP.Net with C# and use MS SQL server as backend database

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internationalization of ASP.NET apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251032/internationalization-of-asp-net-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly don't want to create separate pages for each language.

ASP.NET is quite well geared towards multiple-languages within one page - with the use of [resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> An effective way to create localized
>   Web pages is to use resources for your
>   page's text and controls based on the
>   user's language and culture. By using
>   properties placed in resource objects,
>   ASP.NET can select the correct
>   property at run time according to the
>   user's language and culture.

Answer (score 0):

Using resource files can be a bit of a nightmare for large sites, you may want to check this database resource provider out, although you would have to edit resources from the database as the visual studio resource editor only works with file-based resources.

[Implementing a database resource provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx)